# How to monitor FPGA signals on the simulator

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I have an FPGA project on Vivado in VHDL that contains lots of components, let's call them 'blocks'. I am testing these 'blocks' individually before integrating them together for the final design.

Anyway I am creating a separate source file for each block, where each block contains sometimes 3 or 4 components with signals connecting between them. I then write a suitable testbench source file to test the block. Now as the signals between components isn't in the entity port map of the file, I can't map them into my testbench file to view the signals on simulation.

My question is: Is there a way to view signals declared in my main source file in my testbench simulation file?

**EDIT**

Hopefully this will shed more information to my problem. I have pasted my project hierarchy, files and images. This is a 4 bit register with an enabler. I know the design works perfect as the register stores and enables the output fine, I would just like to see the stored register value in simulation as it is stored on signal wires passing between the register and enabler components. I think you only need to see the topo_level files as it contains the signals!

**Simulation Image**

[image: Simulation Image]

**Project hierarchy**

[image: Project Overview Image]

**Top_Level file**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use work.Architecture_size.ALL;

entity Top_Level is
 Port ( Data_in : in std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0);
        Reset_in : in std_logic;
        Clock_in : in std_logic;
        Enable_in : in std_logic;
        Data_out : out std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0)
      );
end Top_Level;

architecture Layout of Top_Level is

component D_Type_FF_Register is
 Port ( D : in std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0);
        Clock : in std_logic;
        Reset : in std_logic;
        Q : out std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0)
      );
end component;          

component Enabler_Block is
 Port ( A : in std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0);
        Enable : in std_logic;
        Q : out std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0)
      );
end component;

signal temp_wires : std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0);

begin

Register_instance : D_Type_FF_Register port map (D => Data_in , Q => temp_wires , Clock => Clock_in, Reset => Reset_in); 
Enabler_instance : Enabler_Block port map (A => temp_wires , Q => Data_out , Enable => Enable_in);

end Layout;
```

**Top_Level_TB file

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use work.Architecture_size.ALL;
 
entity Top_Level_TB is
end Top_Level_TB;
 
architecture simulation of Top_Level_TB is 
 
component Top_Level is
 Port ( Data_in : in std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0);
        Reset_in : in std_logic;
        Clock_in : in std_logic;
        Enable_in : in std_logic;
        Data_out : out std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0));
 end component; 
  
   signal Data_in_TB  : std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal Clock_in_TB : std_logic := '0';
   signal Reset_in_TB : std_logic := '0';
   signal Enable_in_TB : std_logic := '0';
   signal Data_out_TB : std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0);
   signal temp_wires_TB : std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
 
   constant clock_period : time := 10 ns;
 
begin
 
   uut: Top_Level port map (
          Data_in => Data_in_TB,
          Clock_in => Clock_in_TB,
          Reset_in => Reset_in_TB,
          Enable_in => Enable_in_TB,
          Data_out => Data_out_TB);

   clock_process :process
   begin
        Clock_in_TB <= '0';
        wait for clock_period/2;
        Clock_in_TB <= '1';
        wait for clock_period/2;
   end process;
 
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
     
     wait for 100 ns;   

     wait for clock_period*10;
       
     Reset_in_TB <= '0';
     Enable_in_TB <= '0';
     Data_in_TB <= (others => '0');
     wait for clock_period*2;
     
     Reset_in_TB <= '0';
     Enable_in_TB <= '0';
     Data_in_TB <= (others => '1');
     wait for clock_period*2;
     
     Reset_in_TB <= '0';
     Enable_in_TB <= '0';
     Data_in_TB <= (others => '0');
     wait for clock_period*2;
     
     Reset_in_TB <= '0';
     Enable_in_TB <= '0';
     Data_in_TB <= (others => '1');
     wait for clock_period*2;
     
     Reset_in_TB <= '0';
     Enable_in_TB <= '1';
     Data_in_TB <= (others => '1');
     wait for clock_period*2;
     
     Reset_in_TB <= '0';
     Enable_in_TB <= '0';
     Data_in_TB <= (others => '1');
     wait for clock_period*2;
    
   end process;

end;
```

Comment: In simulation settings tick the log all signals, then run the simulation, now if u click the module in hierarchy u will see the signals toggling when u add them to waveform viewer

Comment: Will give this a try, thanks

Comment: This should be pretty straight forward. Just drop down box in simulation.

Comment: Well I can see the signals in the simulation waveform viewer but they never change.

Comment: @RAMAKRISHNAMEDA See above comment

Comment: @MituRaj See baove comment

Comment: @david share the pic, is it showing NA/grey colour or is it showing no toggling

Comment: @RAMAKRISHNAMEDA See my edited question, The trace is green ok but it just doesn't toggle. I have ticked the "log all signals" in simulation settings as you said.

Comment: @David777, you are showing `signal temp_wires_TB : std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');` of entity `Top_Level_TB` in your simulation whereas you have `signal temp_wires : std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0);` in your `Top_Level` entity. I think that is the difference.

Comment: Which signal you think is supposed to be toggling here.

Comment: @tim Yeah because I am unsure if I can update them from the main file to the testbench file without being port mapped?

Comment: @MituRaj The temp_wires_TB is what I want to see update. However as Tim has pointed out above this signal hasn't been assigned anything

Comment: @David777, I haven't used the Xilinx Vivado tool chain for a while, but you should be able to expand the design hierarchy in the simulator and pick the signals you want to show, i.e. `temp_wires`. The equivalent in Modelsim is to expand the hierarchy or find the signal/variable/constant in the source file window, right-click on it and choose "Add Wave". There should be something similar in Vivado.

Comment: @tim,ok thanks, give me a second. I'll have a look now.

Comment: @tim No I am unsure how to do that.

Comment: @David777, does [this](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Welcome-Join/How-to-add-new-signals-for-waveform-simulation/td-p/279628) help?

Comment: @tim Yes, this helped I managed to get it on the waveform display. Leave an answer with this link and I will accept. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing `signal temp_wires_TB : std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');` of entity `Top_Level_TB` in your simulation whereas you have `signal temp_wires : std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0);` in your `Top_Level` entity. I think that is the difference.

I haven't used the Xilinx Vivado tool chain for a while, but you should be able to expand the design hierarchy in the simulator and pick the signals you want to show, i.e. `temp_wires`, something like this: [How to add new signals for waveform simulation](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Welcome-Join/How-to-add-new-signals-for-waveform-simulation/td-p/279628)

The equivalent in Modelsim is to expand the hierarchy or find the signal/variable/constant in the source file window, right-click on it and choose "Add Wave". There should be something similar in Xilinx Vivado.